# Nested Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript functions for pagination and truncate as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//path/js/jquery.quick.pagination.min.js"></script>
$("#post_list").quickPagination({
    pagerLocation:"both",
    pageSize:"3"
});

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//path/js/jquery.dotdotdot.js"></script>
$(".post_detail").dotdotdot({
after: 'a.more',
callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {
    if (!isTruncated) {
        $('.more',this).remove()
    } 
},
});
```

Each runs fine onLoad. However, once the pagination function is fired, the truncate function does not run again.

Please see my jsfiddle and click page 2 to see the problem.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wr2ezv4f/1/

EDITED:

I managed to include the truncate function by adding it directly to the jquery.quick.pagination.min.js file (Please see the comment inside the js as folow (AND is working well):

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.quickPagination = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            pageSize: 10,
            currentPage: 1,
            holder: null,
            pagerLocation: "after",
            transitionSpeed: null
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var selector = $(this);
            var pageCounter = 1;
            if ($(".simplePagerContainer").length < 1) selector.wrap("<div class='simplePagerContainer'></div>");
            selector.parents(".simplePagerContainer").find("ul.simplePagerNav").remove();
            selector.children().removeClass(function(index, css) {
                return (css.match(/simplePagerPage([0-9]+)?/ig) || []).join(' ');
            }).filter(":visible").each(function(i) {
                if (i < pageCounter * options.pageSize && i >= (pageCounter - 1) * options.pageSize) {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage" + pageCounter);
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage" + (pageCounter + 1));
                    pageCounter++;
                }
            });
            selector.children().hide();
            selector.children(".simplePagerPage" + options.currentPage).show();
            if (pageCounter <= 1) {
                return;
            }
            var pageNav = "<ul class='simplePagerNav'>";
            for (var i = 1; i <= pageCounter; i++) {
                if (i == options.currentPage) {
                    pageNav += "<li class='page currentPage simplePageNav" + i + "'><a rel='" + i + "' href='#'>" + i + "</a></li>";
                } else {
                    pageNav += "<li class='page simplePageNav" + i + "'><a rel='" + i + "' href='#'>" + i + "</a></li>";
                }
            }
            pageNav += "</ul>";
            if (!options.holder) {
                switch (options.pagerLocation) {
                    case "before":
                        selector.before(pageNav);
                        break;
                    case "both":
                        selector.before(pageNav);
                        selector.after(pageNav);
                        break;
                    default:
                        selector.after(pageNav);
                }
            } else {
                $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
            }
            selector.parent().find(".simplePagerNav a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var clickedLink = $(this).attr("rel");
                options.currentPage = clickedLink;
                var container = options.holder ? options.holder : ".simplePagerContainer";
                $(this).parents(container).find("li.currentPage").removeClass("currentPage");
                $(this).parents(container).find("a[rel='" + clickedLink + "']").parent("li").addClass("currentPage");
                selector.children().hide();
                if (options.transitionSpeed) {
                    selector.find(".simplePagerPage" + clickedLink).fadeIn(options.transitionSpeed);
                                        // ** I managed to include the truncate function here **//
                                        $(".post_title").dotdotdot();
                                        $(".post_detail").dotdotdot({
                                                after: 'a.more',
                                                callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {
                                                if (!isTruncated) {
                                                    $('.more',this).remove()
                                                } 
                                            },
                                        });
                } else {
                    selector.find(".simplePagerPage" + clickedLink).show();
                                        //** and to include the truncate function here **//
                                        $(".post_title").dotdotdot();
                                        $(".post_detail").dotdotdot({
                                                after: 'a.more',
                                                callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {
                                                if (!isTruncated) {
                                                    $('.more',this).remove()
                                                } 
                                            },
                                        });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My question now is, how can I modify this js file so that I can include this function outside the js file instead:

Something like:

```
$("#post_list").quickPagination({
        pagerLocation:"both",
        pageSize:"3"
        // ** optional function I want to include here **/
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write both function in a common function like this

```
$(function()
{
    $("#post_list").quickPagination({
        pagerLocation:"both",
        pageSize:"3"
});

$(".post_title").dotdotdot();
$(".post_detail").dotdotdot({
    after: 'a.more',
    callback    : function( isTruncated, orgContent ) {
                     if (!isTruncated) {
                         $('.more',this).remove()
                     } 
                  },
});
});
```

Comment: Your solution looks pretty straight forward but I just can't get it to work. I have added a jsfiddle. Please see if that help my question